# Create non-constant width for UILabel in Interface Builder using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an existing `UILabel` that I created in Interface Builder, I would like to change its width in code, but I can't because of the auto layout. It's pretty simple, I have width from a `CGSize` and I wanna set it for the label. Actually my code works perfectly, I can assign the new size to the label, but unfortunately it doesn't redrawn itself. I've tried to use the `textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:`and `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` without any success or size changes.

```
 float heightIs =
        [cell.lbl.text
         boundingRectWithSize:cell.lbl.frame.size
         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
         attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:cell.lbl.font }
         context:nil]
        .size.height;  


        // get the width size of a string
        CGSize textSize = [cell.lbl.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.lbl.font}];
        CGFloat strikeWidth = textSize.width;

        NSLog(@"TEXT WIDTH %f OF STRING %@", strikeWidth, nameString);

        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake (0, 0, strikeWidth, heightIs);
        cell.lbl.frame = labelFrame;
        cell.lbl.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(labelFrame);
        NSLog(@"LABEL WIDTH VALUE %f", cell.lbl.frame.size.width);
```

Could somebody explain me the right way? I'm not sure that where should I start it. Is it an option somewhere in IB or can I do it with code? Or I can delete all code because it can be done only with IB?

Comment: when using auto layout, the code must change the constraints rather than the frames.  create an outlet to the label's width constraint and change its constant.

Comment: @danh actually I'm not using constraints. I must do it? No other way to do it in code?

Comment: I agree with danh, it has to be something with constrains. If you are not using constrains by yourself, iOs will use the defaults in autoLayout. I think you you have to invesitgate that.

Comment: @bushiko - if you're using auto layout, then you're using constraints.